# QDialog not positioned correctly

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with QDialog which is not displayed centered on the parent window.
The following snippet explains it:

```
void MyWidget::showDialog() {
    QObject* p = parent();
    while (p!=0) {
        qDebug() << p;
        p = p->parent();
    }
    qDebug() << QApplication::activeWindow();

    MyClassDerivedFromQDialog dlg( this );
    if ( dlg.exec() != dlg.Accepted ) {
        return;
    }
    ... do something
}
```

The output on qDebug is the following

```
QSplitter(0x2d89930, name = "splitter") 
MyWidget(0x2d89670, name = "widget") 
MainWindow(0x27ef20, name = "application")
MainWindow(0x27ef20, name = "application")
```

Executing my example opens the dialog somewhere on the screen. Passing QApplication::activeWindow() as a parent to the dialogs constructor results in a dialog centered on the main window. So why is that and how to track down the problem?

Comment: On what systems You've got this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found that this behavior is related to the timing of the dialog creation.
If you create a QDialog (or a derived class) *before* the dialog **parent** is shown (e.g., in the parent constructor), the dialog is displayed at a non-predictable location (or at least, not where you'd expect it to show).
However, if the dialog is created *after* the parent is displayed, then you get the expected behavior.
For example, if you have a button invoking your dialog. Both the button and the dialog are children of the same widget, so the dialog parent is the same as the button parent. In this case, it is advised to delay the dialog creation until the button is clicked, not before that.
This way, you ensure the dialog is created only after the parent is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand your problem.

QDialogs are always centered on the widget you pass as parent. This is by design. So if you pass "activeWindow()" as parent it is centered on the active window. If you pass "this" as a parent the dialog is centered above MyWidget.

In which way does your dialog not respect these rules?

Comment: In the QDialog description it is written that the dialog is centered on the parents top level widget, i.e. The main window. I know that the desription of its exec function is slightly different. With many other qdialog classes it works perfect, and even this particular one works perfect in other places. Anyway, the dialog called from a certain location appears not on the parent widget, it appears on the left side of the screen, half of it out of the desktop and far away from the application window.
I am using qt 5.2 on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Only to make it sure: If you pass "this" as a parent you get the dialog half out of the desktop?

Comment: Yes exactly, but only if i show the Dialog in MyWidget! Using exactly the same code at another position, the exactly same Dialog class works as expected. Thats why i placed the parent stack debug here but i seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Regarding that stack... It says that "this" (which is MyWidget) has a parent QSplitter, that has a parent MyWidget, that has a parent MainWindow. Do you have *two* MyWidget instances that are parent of each other? Also please post the code that creates all of those widgets (constructor or whatever).

Comment: MyClassDerivedFromQDialog::MyClassDerivedFromQDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyClassDerivedFromQDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //remove the ? button in titlebar
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
    Qt::WindowFlags helpFlag = Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
    flags = flags & (~helpFlag);
    setWindowFlags(flags);
}

Answer (score 0):

The Dialog class is instantiated via

```
MyClassDerivedFromQDialog::MyClassDerivedFromQDialog(QWidget *parent) 
: QDialog(parent), 
  ui(new Ui::MyClassDerivedFromQDialog) 
{ 
    ui->setupUi(this); 

    //remove the ? button in titlebar 
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags(); 
    Qt::WindowFlags helpFlag = Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint; 
    flags = flags & (~helpFlag); 
    setWindowFlags(flags); 
}
```

And i always use it as in the showDialog function in the initial post. sometimes it works... And no, i do not have two MyWigets which are parents of each other.

Comment: This is something you should check (I can't see it in the provided code): Why does your debug output show an ancestor "MyWidget" while you think it isn't?! Is there a MyWidget instance you did not intend to create? Is the widget parent of itself? Print out "this" in MyWidget::showDialog() to compare the addresses.

Comment: where do you see the ancestor MyWidget? there are two MainWindows but that is because of the QApplication::activeWindow() written to the debug output